# How can i simulate queue algorithms in OPNET Modeler

Tags: algorithm, networking, queue, simulation, opnet

i'm using OPNET Modeler 14.5 and need to packet drop & delay performance of queue algorithms like blue, sfb, rem,green, yellow and purple algorithms. but i've found only the red's parameter in modeler. How can i find and simulate these algorithms? Pls help...

Answer (score 0):

A quick search gave me the following publication:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3196492_A_comparison_of_active_queue_management_algorithms_using_the_OPNET_Modeler

Check it and don't hesitate to contact the authors for more information.